# How to keep track of css classes in a menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have the following menu that has a `ul > li > a` structure where there are CSS classes added to the `<a>` tag. When the breakpoint is less than 768px, we want to remove the CSS classes. On page load, I can add and remove the CSS classes without an issue, but I am having trouble adding the CSS classes back if the window is resized to be larger than 768px (width).

The tricky part is that the CSS classes may not always be `color--red` for example. They may be different ones like `bkg--black` or something else. I was thinking of storing an array for each `<a>`, but found that in the `on load` and `resize` functions, they do not take the array in.

How would I keep track of the CSS classes per `<a>` and add them back if the window is resized using jQuery?

Here is what we tried

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    if($(window).width() < 768) {
      var el = $('#someid');
      el.find("a").prop("class", function(i, cls) {
        return cls.replace(/(^|\s)(color)--\S+/g, '');
      });
    }
  });
  
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 768) {
      var el = $('#someid');
      el.find("a").prop("class", function(i, cls) {
        return cls.replace(/(^|\s)(color)--\S+/g, '');
      });
    }
    else {
      // Stuck here. 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.color--red { color: red; }
.color--blue { color: blue; }
.color--green { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="someid">
<li><a class="color--red">Seamlessly brand equity invested infomediaries for.</a></li>
<li><a class="color--blue">Seamlessly brand equity invested infomediaries for.</a></li>
<li><a class="color--green">Seamlessly brand equity invested infomediaries for.</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the classes in a local `array` for each element. On `resize` you can obtain the classes back from that local `array`.

```js
$(function() {
  var classList = [];
  var reg = /(^|\s)(color)--\S+/g;
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someid').find('a').each(function(index) {
      classList[index] = $(this).prop('class').match(reg);     
    });
    
    if($(window).width() < 768) {
      var el = $('#someid');
      // Get UL.menu and then remove any color CSS classes from links.
      el.find("a").prop("class", function(i, cls) {
        return cls.replace(reg, '');
      });
    }
  });
  
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 768) {
      var el = $('#someid');
      // Get UL.menu and then remove any color CSS classes from links.
      el.find("a").prop("class", function(i, cls) {
        return cls.replace(reg, '');
      });
    }
    else {
      $('#someid').find('a').each(function(index) {
       classList[index].forEach(color => {
          $(this).addClass(color);
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.color--red { color: red; }
.color--blue { color: blue; }
.color--green { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="someid">
<li><a class="color--red color--cyan">Seamlessly brand equity invested infomediaries for.</a></li>
<li><a class="color--blue">Seamlessly brand equity invested infomediaries for.</a></li>
<li><a class="color--green">Seamlessly brand equity invested infomediaries for.</a></li>
</ul>
```

NOTE: This can also be achieved with CSS `media` queries, but the code must then be hard-coded.

Comment: i ran this and it worked well for when CSS class contains is `color--`. I see that you did `var reg = /(^|\s)(color)--\S+/g;`. Let's say there is no `color--` but instead it only has `bkg--red`, this does always added the value of `reg`

Comment: @usernameabc, well I just tested the regex you provided. Of course you can implement your own `regex` that will work for your cases. Also, the main focus of this question was to solve the *stuck* part you had, not the regex.

Comment: I was just asking to make sure I understood it correctly. I will work on that `regex`.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work with CSS.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .color--red { 
    color: red; 
  }

  .color--blue { 
    color: blue; 
  }
  .color--green { 
    color: green; 
  }
}

.color--red { 
  color: initial; 
}

.color--blue { 
  color: initial; 
}
.color--green { 
  color: initial; 
}
```

```html
<ul id="someid">
<li><a class="color--red">Seamlessly brand equity invested infomediaries for.</a></li>
<li><a class="color--blue">Seamlessly brand equity invested infomediaries for.</a></li>
<li><a class="color--green">Seamlessly brand equity invested infomediaries for.</a></li>
</ul>
```